# Using a for loop to plot arrays from dictionaries

Tags: python, for-loop, plot

I have a dictionary with multiple key defined as (arbitrary inputs):

```py
colors = {}
colors['red'] = {}
colors['blue'] = {}
colors['red'][clustname] = np.array([])
colors['blue'][clustname] = np.array([])
```

basically I want to plot a red v blue graph for each 'cluster'. I have 13 'clusters' in total with differing color values for each. The names in my code are different from the arbitrary ones above, but I figured it would be easier to understand with basic values then to look at the overall code:

```py
colpath = '/home/jacob/PHOTOMETRY/RESTFRAME_COLOURS/'    #This is the path to the restframe colors


goodcolindx = {}
colfiledat = {}
colors = {}
colors['UMINV'] = {}
colors['VMINJ'] = {}
colors['NUVMINV'] = {}
colors['id'] = {}

for iclust in range(len(clustname)):    
    colors['UMINV'][clustname[iclust]] = np.array([])
    colors['VMINJ'][clustname[iclust]] = np.array([])
    colors['id'][clustname[iclust]] = np.array([])
    colors['NUVMINV'][clustname[iclust]] = np.array([])
    filepath = catpath + clustname[iclust] + "_totalall_" + extname[iclust] + ".cat"
    photdat[clustname[iclust]] = ascii.read(filepath) 

    filepath = zpath + "compilation_" + clustname[iclust] + ".dat"
    zdat[clustname[iclust]] = ascii.read(filepath)

    colfilepath = colpath + 'RESTFRAME_MASTER_' + clustname[iclust] + '_indivredshifts.cat'
    colfiledat[clustname[iclust]] = ascii.read(colfilepath)  


    goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]] = np.where((colfiledat[clustname[iclust]]['REDSHIFTUSED'] > 0.9) & \
                                              (colfiledat[clustname[iclust]]['REDSHIFTUSED'] < 1.5) & \
                                              (photdat[clustname[iclust]]['totmask'] == 0) & \
                                           (photdat[clustname[iclust]]['K_flag'] == 0) & \
                    ((zdat[clustname[iclust]]['quality'] == 3) | (zdat[clustname[iclust]]['quality'] == 4)))
    goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]] = goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]][0]

    for igood in range(len(goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]])):

        idstring = str(photdat[clustname[iclust]]['id'][goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]][igood]])

        colors['NUVMINV'][clustname[iclust]] = np.append(colors['NUVMINV'][clustname[iclust]], -2.5 * 
                                                         np.log10(colfiledat[clustname[iclust]]['NUV'][goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]][igood]]
                                                                  / colfiledat[clustname[iclust]]['V'][goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]][igood]]))'SpARCS-0035'


        colors['UMINV'][clustname[iclust]] = np.append(colors['UMINV'][clustname[iclust]], colfiledat[clustname[iclust]]['UMINV'][goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]][igood]])
        colors['id'][clustname[iclust]] = np.append(colors['id'][clustname[iclust]], photdat[clustname[iclust]]['id'][goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]][igood]])
        colors['VMINJ'][clustname[iclust]] = np.append(colors['VMINJ'][clustname[iclust]], colfiledat[clustname[iclust]]['VMINJ'][goodcolindx[clustname[iclust]][igood]])

for iclustc in colors:
    plt.plot(colors['VMINJ'][clustname[iclustc]], colors['UMINV'][clustname[iclustc]], 'ko')
    plt.show()
```

So in this case, my 'red' is the VMINJ and my 'blue' is the UMINV. I am trying to use a for loop to cycle through all the cluster names that I have, but I keep getting the error back 'String indices must be integers'. I understand the basics of that, but don't know how to fix my code to make plots for each 'red' v 'blue' for each cluster. Any help would be awesome, let me know if you have questions

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed the for loop to:

```py
for iclust in range(len(clustname)):
plt.plot(colors['UMINV'][clustname[iclust]]....
```

and that worked